# How can I stop the text of a button flowing onto a new line in Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a button where the text size is set based on the width of the screen however I find that when the button gets too big ie on a tablet, the text flows onto the next line despite having adequate space to display all the text on one line.

Button Code:

```
 DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        float buttonTextSize = width/4;

        button.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, buttonTextSize);
```

Button xml:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start"
        android:textColor="#F5F5F5"
        android:textSize="100dp"
        app:backgroundTint="#000080"
        app:cornerRadius="10dp"
        app:fontFamily="@font/digital"
        app:strokeColor="#000000"
        app:strokeWidth="6dp" />
```

[result on tablet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeLdF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure what was causing it but a work around is just to scale the minimum button width.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the button width to `match_parent` and check if it still breaks. If not, then the problem lies with the text size that you're setting in Java. Try setting the buttonTextSize to some different values by dividing by 6-12 and check which one fits you.

```
float buttonTextSize = width/8;
```

Let me know the update.